# Dynamic Link Resolving issue in Tridion with multiple websites configured as Virtual directory in IIS

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, dynamic-linking

On our staging server, we have a website with name: http://staging.###solutions.com. Inside this website, we have created a number of Virtual directories for each of the different locale/Country such as: cz_cz for Czech Republic, nz_nz for New Zealand.

The issue we are facing is when viewed in browser, the internal Links aren't resolving correctly. For example, as seen below, in the Link the Path is actually correct except that the Locale directory [cz_cz or nz_nz] is missing.

The URL should have been: ...solutions.com/cz_cz/Brand/Brandlist.aspx and not like: ...solutions.com/Brand/BrandList.aspx
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding below settings in `cd_link_conf.xml` file ( the Dynamic Link Resolver configuration file ):

```
<Publications>

<Publication Id="100"> <!-- set id to your Publications ID -->
<!-- Set the Domain to complete Virtual Path of Website in IIS -->
<!-- And Set the Path to "/" as below -->
<Host Domain="staging.###solutions.com/cz_cz" Port="80" Path="/" />
<Linking ComponentAnchors="false" AddComponentLinkInfo="false" />
</Publication>

</Publications>
```

Also, you may try removing the virtual path from `Domain` attribute and specify the virtual directory in `Path` attribute as `Path="/cz_cz"`

```
<Host Domain="staging.###solutions.com" Port="80" Path="/cz_cz" />
```

Either of the settings should work.

Comment: Where can I find this file: cd_link_conf ?

Comment: check the bin/config/ folder of the site

Comment: Thanks R.C. This solution worked perfectly! Can you please point me to the Documents where I can read more on this configuration file ?

Comment: Check this Link: http://media.leidenuniv.nl/legacy/ContentDeliveryReferenceGuide_51SP4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that Dynamic Linking does not know that you are hosting the sites (publications) under sub folders.

You can resolve this by doing one of the following:

- Updating your dynamic linking configuration, as per [R.C.'s answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/12811/25)
- Changing you publication's properties in Tridion to include the subfolder name in the Publication URL and republish your content

Check your images too... Depending on your configuration, If you have not set your Images URL accordingly in publication properties then you may not be referencing the correct images. Dynamic Linking may not help here.

Comment: Yes, I checked my Publication's property and the Images URL is set  there.  I doubt I can change the Publication URL as the setup is different on Live

Comment: Thanks David. Your answer did helped me understand the issue at hand.